# C# XAML ItemsSource BindingExpression

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a GridView with this code

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollectionViewSource}}>
```

How I can transform the Binding to C# code?

Comment: why not you just use `gridviewname.ItemSource = MyCollectionViewSource`

Comment: With "gridviewname.ItemSource = MyCollectionViewSource" give me a error: "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Comment: use `gridviewname.ItemsSource = MyCollectionViewSource` not **ItemSource** if you are still getting the error then the viewmodel needs to be reviewed

Comment: I'm using .ItemsSource sorry, but thanks for the help, I will review...

Comment: @BrunoMiguel does the code you have specified works when you are doing it through xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM pattern, then take a loot at this url:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

First of all you have to create the view-model, then you have to set the view's view-model as it's DataContext. Then you can bind whatever property or command in your VM right into your View.

Answer (score 0):

This should be somewhere in the code behind

```
this.gridView.ItemsSource = this.FindName("MyCollectionViewSource ") as CollectionViewSource;
```